# Running curl from a remote server using PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have this type of curl statement

curl -u xxx:yyy -d "aaa=111" http://someapi.com/someservice

I would like to run this varying aaa=bbb from a list

UPDATE: Code that works, built on Jimmy's code

```
<?PHP
$data = array('Aaa', 'Bbb', 'Ccc');
echo $data;    
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:')); //Fixes the HTTP/1.1 417 Expectation Failed Bug

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "xxx:yyy");

foreach ($data as $param) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://...?aaa='.$param);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo "<hr>".$response; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, the code would look different since you'd probably want to use the [built-in cURL client](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) rather than `exec()` (edited to include a loop):

```
$data = array('111', '222', 'ccc');    

foreach ($data as $param)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    $params = array('aaa' => $param);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://someapi.com/someservice');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "xxx:yyy");

    /* used for POST
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    */

    // for GET, we just override the URL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://someapi.com/someservice?aaa='.$param);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Comment: Okee, that is acceptable. Can you do me one with more than one aaa ? i.e. aaa=111, aaa=222, aaa=ccc and a for loop with the response? - thanks

Comment: Thanks - can't I move the curl_init and all the setopts except the postfields outside the loop?

Comment: You can try it - I'm not sure how cURL builds that object and if you need to reinitialize it each time.

Comment: @Jimmy, I get  Expect: 100-continue so can we make it a GET instead of POST?

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, you'd probably use [`LWP`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/lib/LWP.pm) as it is contained in the standard distribution.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;

my $host = 'localhost'; # 'someapi.com';
my $url  = "http://$host/someservice";

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( keep_alive => 1 );
$ua->credentials( $host, 'your realm', 'fridolin', 's3cr3t' );

for my $val ( '111', '222', '333' ) {
    my $req = POST $url, [aaa => $val];
    $req->dump; # debug output
    my $rsp = $ua->request( $req );
    if ( $rsp->is_success ) {
        print $rsp->decoded_content;
    } else {
        print STDERR $rsp->status_line, "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I think I will stay in PHP if this kind of complexity is needed.